# Unable to run the unit test in visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

Unable to run the unit test in visual studio 2017 professional, **Run Selected Tests** is disabled.

[image]

I have tried to rebuild the test project and also the solution.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No, I don't see any error, it's just that I am not able to run my unit test, the run option is disabled.

Comment: please review this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try restart VS, you may be able to see then

Comment: Make sure your class or UT is public. If its private it wont show up.

Answer (score 0):

Set Project solution from Release Mode to Debug Mode..

Comment: Just a reminder, in the screenshot I have provided it's in Debug mode only.