# Debug/run tests option keeps disabling in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am new to c# and visual studio. I am trying to run/debug unit tests but the option to run/debug tests gets disabled after I select a test and right click. If I restart visual studio, it comes back at times. I am not sure what is wrong. I end up restarting my visual studio many times a day. I am running it as an admin.

Comment: did you compile before running unit test?

Comment: @Alexan yes I did clean and build.

Comment: can you run from test explorer?

Comment: even on test explorer the option to run selected test is disabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945195/unable-to-run-the-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2017-professional

Comment: Restart VS. As pointed out in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945195/unable-to-run-the-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2017-professional